# Reading from sockets and download speed

Tags: python, sockets

Just for fun, I develop a download manager and I'd like to know if reading a large stack of data (i.e. 80 or 100KB) from a socket over the net makes the download speed higher, instead of reading 4KB for each loop iteration?

(My average download speed is 200KBPS when I download a file with firefox for example)

Thanks, Nir Tayeb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is **NO**.

your network transfer rate (200kbps) indicates that buffering 4k or 8k or 200k will hardly make a difference. The time spent between reads is too small. The bottleneck seems to be your transfer rate anyway.

Let's try with a [stackoverflow 30.9MB mp3 podcast](http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/shows/detail4253.html):

> ***NOTE***: This is a unreliable hack whose results can be affected by a lot
>   of factors - useful for demonstration
>   purposes only)

```
import urllib2
import time

def report(start, size, text):
    total = time.time() - start
    print "%s reading took %d seconds, transfer rate %.2f KBPS" % (
            text, total, (size / 1024.0) / total)

start = time.time()
url = ('http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/'
       'ITC.SO-Episode69-2009.09.29.mp3')
f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
start = time.time()
data = f.read() # read all data in a single, blocking operation
report(start, len(data), 'All data')
f.close()

f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
start = time.time()
while True:
    chunk = f.read(4096) # read a chunk
    if not chunk:
        break
report(start, len(data), 'Chunked')
f.close()
```

The results in my system:

```
All data reading took 137 seconds, transfer rate 230.46 KBPS
Chunked reading took 137 seconds, transfer rate 230.49 KBPS
```

So for my system, 2 megabit connection, file size, server chosen, it is not much of a difference if I used chunked reading or not.

Comment: I know that my transfer rate is small, but how can I use as much as possible from the transfer rate? how the read function affect on it?

thanks.

Comment: @nirtayeb: Your operational system controls that. Most OSes have no traffic shaping, so you'll get full transfer rate on both methods, unless other process is also using the connection.